# LyX linguistics module - table within example

Tags: floats, lyx, positioning, linguistics, covington

Using LyX with the linguistics module.
I want to have a table as a Numbered Example. When I insert a table float after the example, the number appears *after* the table on the PDF, rather than before it.

Edit: Floats are set to appear "here definitely", but the problem persists.

The .lyx file relevant section:

```
\begin_body

\begin_layout Numbered Example (multiline)
\begin_inset Float table
wide false
sideways false
status open
\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="1" columns="1">
<features tabularvalignment="middle">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="0">
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" leftline="true" rightline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
a
\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, with a table float within a numbered example, the table appears after the example number when set to *here definetely*. Can you trim your document down to the minimum showing the problem, and edit your question to include the contents of the `.lyx` file (it is just plain text, you can open it in a text editor) or at least the exported LaTeX source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems only to happen when there is no text before the table float within the example, though exactly why I cannot say. If you don't want any text before the table, a workaround seems to be to insert a `\hfill` right after the example number. You can do that either by adding an ERT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) and writing `\hfill` in it, or by choosing Insert --> Formatting --> Horizontal Space, and selecting Horizontal fill.

However, floats does not seem to respect the indentation in the `examples` environment. A workaround for this is to not use a float, but a `minipage`. This does not require any tricks such as `\hfill`. It does however require writing the caption in an ERT, and you have to set the width of the `minipage`:

1. At the start of the Example, do Insert --> Box --> Frameless.
2. In the settings of this box, set the width to a little less than 100% of the column width, say 98%. The reason is that `\columnwidth` seems to be a little bit more than full text width minus the indentation, so with 100% the `minipage` will stick into the margin a little. (This is not ideal, I know, but my best suggestion after fifteen minutes of trying.)
3. Go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add

   ```
   \usepackage{capt-of}
   ```

   (If you have this or `\usepackage{caption}` already, then you don't have to do this.)
4. Inside the minipage, to create a table caption, add an ERT and write

   ```
   \captionof{table}{This is your caption.}
   ```

Comment: Not a very good answer, I know, but it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! This does work (in fact, it seems like adding any element, such a hard-space works), however it also gets rid of the indentation of the table for some reason...

Comment: @HenryBrice I don't get any indentation with or without the `\hfill`, do you? I'll update my answer with another workaround that takes care of both problems.

Comment: Thanks, the workaround seems to work perfectly. Thank you very much!